# How to transcode HEVC footage on a mac if you don't have CC2018 yet

Tags: premiere, transcoding, mac, hevc

Is there a good free way to convert iPhone HEVC footage to .mov prores or something similar using a Mac (MacOS 10.12) with Premiere CC 2017?  Googling provides lots of unreliable looking apps from companies I haven't heard of. Any good (preferably free) recommendations?

Comment: The other question says Windows/Linux, but the top voted applies to macOS as well.

Comment: Not really. I’m not using windows or Linux. I don’t necessarily need ProRes, just any high quality format suitable for editing on Premiere CC 2017

Comment: Please read the first answer of the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with handbrake.  It's a free GUI program for performing transcodes.  It is even used to benchmark processors and graphics cards.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Open Terminal.
Install FFMPEG with extra features by entering the following on a single line:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-libass  --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opus --with-x26
```

Wait about 10 minutes for it to install.

From the Terminal, run FFMPEG, using a line like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v prores -profile:v 3 -c:a pcm_s16le output.mov
```

`input.mov` is the name of your HEVC file.  It can also include a full path, but spaces need to be preceded by backslashes  “\”

`output.mov` is an exported ProRes quicktime movie that will play in Premiere

Do process more than one file at a time:

In terminal, go to the directory where your files are.

```
for i in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v prores -profile:v 3 -c:a pcm_s16le "${i%.*}_out.mov"; done
```

Output files will appear in the same folder appended with “_out.mov”